# HTML5 Boilerplate: difference between script.js and plugins.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, boilerplate

i can't find any definitive answer on the boilerplate docs, but can someone clarify the difference between plugins.js, and script.js? i'm a javascript newbie, and am tempted to just put all my scripts in one file... is there a good reason not to do this?

Comment: Now there is [a document](http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/plugins.js-and-script.js/) explaining that.

Answer (score 1):

From [the FAQ](http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/#FAQs%E2%98%85how-should-scriptjs-and-pluginsjs-be-used-what-should-go-in-these-files):

> Script.js should hold your primary application script. It might make sense to store it in an [object literal and execute it based on body classes](http://paulirish.com/2009/markup-based-unobtrusive-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/).
>
> Plugins I use for jQuery plugins and other 3rd party scripts myself. I put the jQuery plugins inside of the `(function($){ ... })(jQuery);` closure to make sure they're in the jQuery namespace safety blanket, especially if they were written by more amateur developers. See also [jQuery Plugin Authoring](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Getting_Started).

Answer (score 0):

in `plugins.js` file you get few helpers bundled, it's probably meant to include stuff you won't modify at all (or at least not so often), while `script.js` is a file ready for your... yes, scripts. ;)

what you said is true - in production, it's usually better to serve the browser one file instead of many. however in development it's easier to keep things separated.
that's the reason why boilerplate comes with a build script, which combines all your scripts into one so you don't have to worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

in scripts -> your custom scripts
in plugings -> don't touch it!

In build process both files unite into one unique and compressed file...